# PowerMock Throwing an Exception from @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) Annotation

Tags: java, junit, jar, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to get PowerMockito working with my application.  I've added the library to the build path.  I have the following test class:

```
package client.controller;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(System.class)
public class SampleTest
{
    @Test
    public void test()
    {

    }
}
```

When I try to run the tests, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/internal/runners/TestClassRunner
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.legacy.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 31 more
```

According to the [PowerMock FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/FAQ), I should try using the legacy package.  I did, and I'm still getting the same exception.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is the JAR that contains `org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner` on the classpath?

Comment: It appears to have been removed/renamed in JUnit 4.5 and possibly earlier.

Comment: I'm using JUnit 4.8.2.  How do I check the class path?  If I try to import that package, Eclipse tells me it cannot be resolved.

Comment: When looking at the PowerMock FAQ, it mentioned the legacy package for use with JUnit 3. Are you sure you're supposed to be using it?

Comment: Also you can't mock `System` methods like that as it is in `rt.jar`, i.e. it is a _system class_. Here's how you should proceed : http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockSystem

Comment: @David Harkness: Sorry for the late reply. I tried switching out the packages to the legacy versions but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I was adding PowerMock to the build incorrectly.  When I looked through the problems view in Eclipse, I found the following:

```
Archive for required library: 'lib/powermock-mockito-junit-1.4.11 4/powermock-release-junit-without-mock-framework-1.4.11.pom' in project 'Test' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file  Test        Build path  Build Path Problem
Archive for required library: 'lib/powermock-mockito-junit-1.4.11 4/powermock-release-without-test-and-mock-framework-1.4.11.pom' in project 'Test' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file   Test        Build path  Build Path Problem
```

Removing these two files from the build path fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

For me the the confusion started with junit versioning,

apparently 4.12 > 4.4 in junit versions.

So for versions > 4.4, you need to use `powermock-module-junit4`

instead of `powermock-module-junit4-legacy`.

As a side note, later I found out I have to use `powermock-api-mockito2`

instead of `powermock-api-mockito`

That's progress...

Maven instructions:
https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-Maven